# Gangster movie about a group of orphans under the care of a priest

Tags: identify-this-movie

A group of poor orphan boys are under care of a priest. Some of the elders of this group join the gangsters in robbing a bank and make some of wishes of the younger's true (buy them clothes, ball etc.). One of them becomes a famous gangster.

The priest takes them to a school and tries to change their future. The famous young gangster gets arrested by police and is sentenced to death.

The priest goes to him at jail and asks him to cry when he is going for execution because he is the hero of boys and they will follow his way unless they think he has been regretful in the last moments. Young gangster replies, pride is the last thing I have when leaving this world and denies his request.

Tomorrow when boys read newspapers they find that gangster was begging for his life when he was getting for execution.

Comment: Awesome story. Would like to see this question gets answered.

Comment: BDW any idea about it's timing?

Comment: @Mistu4u: Yes, the story is great. I saw it 20 years ago and still remember it as one of the best movies ever seen. What the gangster did for boys to me is the most that one can sacrifice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it's [Angels with Dirty Faces](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0029870/).

From the Wikipedia entry:

> Rocky is then captured following an elaborate shootout in a building,
>   and sentenced to die. Jerry visits him just before his execution and
>   asks him to do him one last favor - to die pretending to be a
>   screaming, sniveling coward, which would end the boys' idolization of
>   him.

Comment: James Cagney at his finest.

Comment: @KevinHowell - Funnily enough, I've never seen the movie. But a friend of mine raves about it a lot LOL. Might need to move it up a few spots in my To-See list.